# Django Rendering Form in HTML Issue

Tags: python, django, forms, django-forms

I'm attempting to render a form, in html and have tried the normal {{ form }}. However when I go to the site set up by: ***python manage.py runserver***. I get the following where the form should go (highlighted section on screen-capture)

[webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/80YKk.png)

This is the code for the form in question.

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.forms import ChoiceField, ModelForm, RadioSelect
from .models import command_node
from .models import beacon


class Command_Form(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = command_node
        fields = (
            'host_id',
            'current_commands'
        )
        
        host_id = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            required=True,
            queryset=beacon.objects.all(),
            widget=forms.Select(
                attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                },
            )
        )

        current_comamnds = forms.ChoiceField(
            required=True,

            choices=[
                ('Sleep', "Sleep"),
                ('Open SSH_Tunnel', 'Open SSH_Tunnel'),
                ('Close SSH_Tunnel', 'Close SSH_Tunnel'),
                ('Open TCP_Tunnel', 'Open TCP_Tunnel'),
                ('Close TCP_Tunnel', 'Close TCP_Tunnel'),
                ('Open Dynamic', 'Open Dynamic'),
                ('Close Dynamic', 'Close Dynamic'),
                ('Task', 'Task'),
            ])
```

This is the html in question. I've removed non-relevant segments

home.html

```html
</br>
</br>
    <form action="" method=POST>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <button type="Submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Lastly I've included the views as I suspect it might have something to do with it but I'm not certain. I'm trying to make it so that when the form is submitted the page is reloaded.

Views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from .models import beacon
from .models import command_node
from .forms import Command_Form
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def home(request):
    form = Command_Form,
    if request.method == "POST":
            form = form(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form})

    return render(request, 'home.html', {"form": form},)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
form = Command_Form()
if request.method == "POST":
    form = Command_Form(request.POST)
```

I believe you are not instantiating the model and that's the problem.

Comment: Forms are also written in `PascalCase` with `Form` to be the suffix, kindly mention that it is better if it is `CommandForm` not `Command_Form`.

Comment: Yeah agree but the code he shared is not using camel case and also the question is in other direction than code format or conventions.

Comment: I am talking `PascalCase` not `camelCase`. Anyway, later onwards I will edit your answer.

Comment: Well upper camel case. But is not the question I believe. Make the suggestion in the question.